# MS Access error, aggregate function

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I am trying to run the sql query below in access. I keep getting the MS Access error:

> "You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'ID' as part of an aggregate function"

The query I wrote is as below:

```
SELECT Subject.ID, Subject.Description, Max(DataSets.ID) AS ID_DataSets
FROM Subject 
INNER JOIN DataSets ON Subject.Description = DataSets.Subject.Value
GROUP BY Subject.ID, Subject.Description;
```

Comment: Are you sure about this relation Subject.Description = DataSets.Subject.Value ?

Comment: MS Access only works with one period qualifier between table name/alias and field unless escaped by brackets or backticks. Please explain `DataSets.Subject.Value`.

Comment: Chetan Vasudevan - Yes I'm sure about that relation. I would have liked it if it was an 'ID' that linked the 2 tables but I didn't create the tables unfortunately

Comment: @Parfait - the 'Subject' field on the DataSets table is a multivalued field and I need to display individual values

Comment: I advise to not use multivalued fields (strays from normalized model of relational databases). Use a one-to-many join table which works better in SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

I see an error in this reference `DataSets.Subject.Value`, but I'm not sure it would generate that error message.  Try this version:

```
SELECT s.ID, s.Description, Max(ds.ID) AS ID_DataSets
FROM Subject as s INNER JOIN
     DataSets as ds
     ON s.Description = ds.Value  -- is this correct?
GROUP BY s.ID, s.Description;
```

I find queries easier to write and read when they use table aliases.

Comment: I accept that writing aliases is really the best way I really dont know how the person arrived at DataSets.Subject.Value ? Thats the reason I commented it out there.If the question asker is wrong at that part of relationship, then your query must be a perfect answer

Comment: *I see an error* ... for future readers please advise what this error was that you saw.